# extract the row of the text files based on minimum value in the column

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

i have many text files(.txt) files in the directory that contain 5 columns as sample data given below:

data1.txt

```
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.0 
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5 
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 2.3 
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.9 
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.1 
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 1.5
```

I need to extract the row which contain the minimum value in the 5th column

```
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5
```

and then i want to save the extracted file in the same file name in another fresh directory `/home/lijun/new_data/data1.txt`

I tried the code below for doing the same but it doesnot show any results...hope some results from experts.Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/lijun/data/*.txt
do
awk '{if $5=min}' $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```sh
for file in /home/lijun/old_data/*.txt; do
    cp "$(sort -n -k 5,5 "$file" | head -n 1 | cut -f 1)" /home/lijun/new_data/
done
```

The `-n` flag is for a numeric sort, and the `-k 5,5` is for sorting by the 5th column (delimited by whitespace by default). `head -n 1` takes only the first line. `cut -f 1` extracts the filename. This all is wrapped in command substitution `$()` for a copy command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222281/discussion-on-answer-by-mitchell-p-extract-the-row-of-the-text-files-based-on-mi).

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly improve the efficiency of how you isolate record with the minimum fifth field and write it to a `newdata` subdirectory by simply using `awk`. A single-process to handle the entire affiar.

With `awk` you would simply declare a variable say `i` and set it larger than the largest minimum value you have. Since there is no equivalent to `INT_MAX` in C, you can simply set the variable value to a large number (one million below). Then you simply loop comparing the fifth-field with the variable, and if the fifth field is less, save it as the new variable value and store the record (line) in another.

You use the file record number `FNR` to check if you are processing the first line in the file. If so, save the filename as the last filename seen (e.g. `lastfn`). To control output, you will check if you have a minimum record save. If so, then the `lasfn` will hold the filename of the current minimum record and you can redirect that to your `newdata` directory in the same filename. Then in the `END` rule, you simply output the saved record and redirect it to a new file of the same name in the `newdata` directory.

Change to the directory containing all your `*.txt` files and create the `newdata` directory, e.g. (`mkdir -p newdata`); Then:

You can do it as a one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {if (lastfn) print rec > "newdata/" lastfn; lastfn=FILENAME; i=100000} {if ($5<i) {i=$5;rec=$0}} END {print rec > "newdata/" FILENAME}' *.txt
```

Or in a multi-line format, which may be readable, e.g.

```
awk 'FNR==1 {
    if (lastfn)
        print rec > "newdata/" lastfn
        lastfn = FILENAME
        i = 100000
}
{
    if ($5 < i) {
        i = $5
        rec = $0
    }
}
END {
    print rec > "newdata/" FILENAME
}' *.txt
```

**Example Output**

Created in the `newdata` directory you would find:

```
$ cat newdata/data1.txt
/home/lijun/data   1.0  2.0 5.0 0.5
```

You will now have one data file per filename in the `newdata` directory.